# Can I update css in server side less compilation mode in magento 2?

Tags: css, magento-2.0

Now, my website has `Server side less compilation` mode enabled. I want to change CSS for any specific section but it is not updating. If I change the compilation mode `client side less` then my website has a broken design. So Please tell me, How can I update CSS?

Comment: After updating your CSS run upgrade/deploy commands and also production commands if site broke... This will solve your problem

Comment: I have run commands multiple times and the site is developer mode.

Comment: have you extended your less file in your theme directory : web/css/source/_extend.less.

Comment: I am changing Theme/web/css/source/_theme.less

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should add your own style on `.less` file. You can override the default styles instead of making changes on original CSS files.

Then, you need to use **Grunt** to compile your LESS files into CSS. After you followed the install and configuration part, run the command `grunt less:<theme_code>`. You should see the effect after refresh.

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html